# MIPS offsets with variables

Tags: variables, mips, offset

When I load a variable using 4-byte offset, how would I load that variable into an array?

For example... if I have the C assignment statement:

```
B[8] = A[i] + A[j]

lw $t0, 4j($s6)    # load A[j] into $t0
lw $ti, 4i($s6)    # load A[i] into $t1
add $t0, $t0, $t1  # Register $t0 gets A[i] + A[j]
sw $t0, 32($s7)    # Stores A[i] + A[j] into B[8]
```

Would this be the correct way to do the offset for variable? The 4j and 4i part is where I'm really confused.

Edit: i and j have the registers $s3 and $s4, but I don't know how to use

Comment: Does that assemble?  I've never seen that syntax for using a variable offset.

Comment: It does not assemble, I can't figure out how to assemble the statement.
I edited, adding extra info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to calculate the offsets:

```
li $s2, 4         # put constant 4 in s2
multu $s2, $s3    # multiply s3 by 4
mflo $s3          # put multiplication result back in s3
multu $s2, $s4    # multiply s4 by 4
mflo $s4          # put multiplication result back in s4
add $s4, $s6, $s4 # s4 = pointer to A[j]
add $s3, $s6, $s3 # s3 = pointer to A[i]
lw $t0, ($s4)     # load A[j] into t0
lw $t1, ($s3)     # load A[i] into t1
add $t0, $t0, $t1 # t0 = A[j] + A[i]
sw $t0, 32($s7)   # B[8] = A[i] + A[j]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume `$s0` stores `i` and `$s1` stores `j`. Base address of `A` and `B` are `$s6`, `$s7` respectively.

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2    #offsets 4*i
sll $t1, $s1, 2    #offsets 4*j
add $t0, $t0, $s6  #Pointer to A[i]
add $t1, $t1, $s6  #Pointer to A[j]
lw $t0, 0($t0)     #loads A[i] to $t0
lw $t1, 0($t1)     #loads A[j] to $t1

add $t2, $t1, $t0  #A[i]+A[j]

sw $t2, 32($s7)    #stores A[i]+A[j] to B[8]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is correct, in ASM language you don't have "variables" you must access a register which contains the i and j, you normaly have a pointer to base array, which seems to be $s6, and your offsets are missing, and its not calculated correctly, what you is use a temporary register to calculate the add $t2, $base, $offset, each in their own register, and then use (What 4i means is number which is 4*i, and 4j is a number which is 4*j, but cannot be inputted directly, as are variables, and are contained withing a register)
lw $ti, $t2

See what I mean? That asm is assuming you are doing i and j multiplication like
4*i and 4*j as offset, but offset can't be a register, so what you do is you add 4 (bytes) assuming each element in the array has size of 4 bytes. assuming the result of 4*i and 4*j are in $t4 and $t5 respectively:

```
add $t1, $s6, $t4
lw $t2, $t1
add $t1, $s6, $t5
lw $t3, $t1
add $t0, $t2, $t3
sw $t0, 32($s7)
```